# OnActivityResult Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-storage

I am currently using firebase storage to allow users to upload images.
I copied my old working java code and is trying to convert it to Kotlin but I have a mismatch issue. The error message is:

**Type mismatch
Required: Uri
Found: Uri?**

Here is my code.

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1046) {
            try {
                val imageUri : Uri? = data?.data
                val imageStream: InputStream? = this.contentResolver.openInputStream(imageUri) //this is the line that errors imageUri has a mismatch error
                val selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream)
                CloudStorage().upload(imageUri,
                    { s ->
                        uploadedImageURL = s
                    }) { e ->
                    Toast.makeText(this@CreatePostActivity, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }

            } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                Toast.makeText(this, "file not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`imageUri` cannot be null since `openInputStream` does not accept nullable values. You can fix it by only executing the code if the value is not nullable, for example:

```
data?.data?.let { imageUri ->
        try {
            val imageStream: InputStream? = this.contentResolver.openInputStream(imageUri)
            val selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream)
            CloudStorage().upload(imageUri,
                { s ->
                    uploadedImageURL = s
                }) { e ->
                Toast.makeText(this@CreatePostActivity, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

        } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Toast.makeText(this, "file not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
} ?: notifyUserImageUriIsNull()
```

Note that you're calling `super.onActivityResult()` twice.

Answer (score 0):

"Android Studio" shows the answers.
[image]